# Does an axle nut require a "deep" socket?

Tags: subaru, tools, hub, wheel-hub

I'm going to replace the front wheel bearing / hub assemblies on a Subaru. The axle nut should be 32 mm.

Will a "deep" socket be needed? If its just a matter of the depth of bore of the hub assembly, I think a socket extension would suffice. But I'm not very familiar with nuts of that size, or if the axle itself might protrude at all and interfere with the socket fitting.

I haven't started any work yet, so I don't have photos of the actual vehicle; but this ought to be the same model:

[image]

(front left)

Comment: You can use a shallow socket on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, any old 32mm socket works on Subaru axle nuts.

If you look at the photo you supplied, there is a notch in the axle (at about 9 oclock). The axle nut will have been hammered into that notch to lock it into place after final torquing. For that reason, it is essential that you always use a new axle nut if you take it off.